# Do browsers always keep an image file in memory?

Tags: html, memory-leaks, canvas, fileapi

I'm using File API to draw local image files on canvas after user drop them on the page. It works fine in Firefox 5 and Google Chrome. The problem is after I drop 500 Mb image files the browser memory consumption increase on about 500 Mb. But I think it should not be so, because after I draw image on canvas there are no more links to the file.
The sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0 none; height: 100%; }
        #container { width: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var el = document.getElementById('container');
        var files = [];
        var image = new Image;
        var URL_ = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

        image.addEventListener('load', function (e) {

            // Free link to the file
            URL_.revokeObjectURL(image.src);

            // Draw image
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = 100;
            canvas.height = 100;
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100);

            el.appendChild(canvas);

            // Process next
            generatePreview();
        }, false);

        el.addEventListener('dragenter', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);

        el.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);

        el.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            files = Array.prototype.slice.call(e.dataTransfer.files, 0);

            generatePreview();
        }, false);

        function generatePreview() {
            if (files.length == 0) return;
            image.src = URL_.createObjectURL(files.shift());
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 'after I draw image on canvas'

I'm not a canvas expert but if you're drawing the image onto a <canvas> element, technically the image data is still part of the webpage.

Comment: Thanks! But if I understand it right, drawing image on canvas is simply take pixels from source image and draw them on canvas. Canvas does not have link to the source image.
And I don't add image object into the DOM, so it should not be the part of the page.